# Upload Angular-locale dynamically

Tags: angularjs, internationalization, angular-ui

I use the `i18n/angular-locale` to manage the data.

In my html page I have a dropdown with the language, when I change the language  I would like to upload the correct `i18n/angular-locale` (for example if I select France to upload `i18n/angular-locale_fr.js`...) there is a dynamically mode to load
 this file instead of to upload all files

Comment: Do you want to dynamically change the language of your application?

Comment: Not the language, the data (November, sunday...).About the language I know how I have to do...

Answer (score 0):

I hope to have understood your question: there's a nice `AngularJS` module called [angular-translate](http://pascalprecht.github.io/angular-translate/#) that let you easily manage all the `i18n` stuff.

Comment: Yes, I know it but for the format/translate date (27 February 2012) I have to use hte i18n